# How can I reset a user's bluetooth service programmatically?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with a low energy device that can be very finicky with certain android phones and when it doesn't connect after a phone restart I want to either reset the android Bluetooth service(clear it's storage) or ask the user to do so.

Is there any way I can do this?